# Saved message in /usr/rp//dead.letter when sending e-mail on CentOS

Tags: centos, email, sendmail

We just changed a server from RHEL to CentOS. We have some scripts which run some reports and e-mail them. The part that does the e-mailing is below.

```
function email_report
{
    ( echo "Report attached."; uuencode report.csv report.csv ) |
    mail -s "Report" john.doe@example.com -- -f noreply@example.com

}
```

but the reports aren't received and we see this message:

> /usr/rp/dead.letter... Saved message in /usr/rp//dead.letter

Does anyone know how to solve this? It is just this script which is causing that message. Other scripts that send e-mail don't have an issue.

Contents of `dead.letter`:

```
From rp Fri Oct  7 11:56:02 2016
Return-Path: <rp>
Received: (from rp@localhost)
        by EXAMPLESERVER.localdomain (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id u97Au2No020739;
        Fri, 7 Oct 2016 11:56:02 +0100
From: rp
Message-Id: <201610071056.u97Au2No020739@EXAMPLESERVER.localdomain>
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 11:56:02 +0100
To: noreply@example.com, -f, --, john.doe@example.com
Subject: Report
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Report attached.
begin 664 OSWHMFHXSF.csv
M15)23U(Z"D]202TQ,C$U-#H@5$Y3.F-O=6QD(&YO="!R97-O;'9E('1H92!C
M;VYN96-T(&ED96YT:69I97(@<W!E8VEF:65D"@H*4U`R+3`S,#8Z($EN=F%L
M:60@;W!T:6]N+@I5<V%G93H@0T].3EM%0U1=(%ML;V=O;ET@6T%3('M365-$
M0D%\4UE33U!%4GU="G=H97)E(#QL;V=O;CX@(#HZ/2`\=7-E<FYA;64^6R\\
M<&%S<W=O<F0^75M`/&-O;FYE8W1?:61E;G1I9FEE<CY=('P@+PI34#(M,#,P
M-CH@26YV86QI9"!O<'1I;VXN"E5S86=E.B!#3TY.6T5#5%T@6VQO9V]N72!;
M05,@>U-94T1"07Q365-/4$52?5T*=VAE<F4@/&QO9V]N/B`@.CH](#QU<V5R
M;F%M93Y;+SQP87-S=V]R9#Y=6T`\8V]N;F5C=%]I9&5N=&EF:65R/ET@?"`O
M"E-0,BTP,34W.B!U;F%B;&4@=&\@0T].3D5#5"!T;R!/4D%#3$4@869T97(@
<,R!A='1E;7!T<RQE>&ET:6YG(%-13"I0;'5S"@``
`
end
```

Comment: Which user is running the script/sending the email? What does dead letter say?

Comment: I have added the contents of `dead.letter`, notice the strange `To:` line. We have old RHEL servers still running this script fine. It's just this new server (CentOS) which can't.

Comment: Are these scripts run via `cron` or some other "non-desktop" method? Look at the "`To:`" Mail header. It seems that whatever `$SHELL` you're using mis-parsed your command. All the text after the "`example.com`" should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

The `dead.letter` thing is easy to explain: This is the standard reaction if a mail should be sent but no method of delivery can be found by the mail-sending software.

So you need to find out why this script does not work while the others don't.

First step to try is to run the mail commands of a succeeding and the failing scripts from the command line. With that, find out whether it is a wrong command-line option (these can vary between distros), or some environmental difference (such as environment variable, or shell aliases, or shell functions).

If you can reproduce the difference on the command line, check the parameters and fix them.
If you cannot, insert a `which mail` line before the mail-sending line in the failing script, so that you see whether it is running the `mail` binary, a shell alias, or a shell function.
If the failing script is running the expected binary, it could be an environment variable that it is setting in a way that fits RHEL but not CentOS.

In other words: Investigate possible differences until you find the culprit.